# Azure Bot in Web Chat testwindow not working

Tags: azure, chatbot

I am not able to make my chatbot work in the web chat test window. It is possible to write something, but there is no answer coming from the bot. However when I download the code and test it in the Bot Emulator, it works!

Since I am new to the whole chatbot topic in Azure I don't know what I am doing wrong or missing. Anybody got an idea what it could be?

[image]

Comment: have you tried to restart the bot? It seems like your message is not sent.

Comment: By restart do you mean clicking on "Start over"? Or how do I restart it?

Comment: Yes, i am start over

Comment: Doesnt help, sorry